# Rendering issue with matplotlib in python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, graphics

I need a program to *draw* slanting, parallel lines in a matrix. This is my python2 code:

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import imshow, show

X, Y, m, s = 500, 1000, 8, 200        
x = np.zeros((Y, X)) 
c = -m * Y              
for i in xrange(Y):
    for j in xrange(X):               
        k = 0                         
        while k * s < 2 * m * Y:
            if i == m * j + c + s * k:
                x[i][j] = 1
            k += 1
imshow(x, aspect='auto'); show()
```

The image produced is: [image]
There is no reason why blocks in between should be missing. I zoomed in on the first region where they were missing and I found that the points were indeed there: [image]

To make sure that that is what the points should look like, here's the region following that, where the original image does render the points: [image]

Is this a rendering issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `np.rollaxis(np.array(np.where(x == 1)), 1)` gives `array([[  0,   0],
       [  0,  25],
       [  0,  50],
       ..., 
       [992, 449],
       [992, 474],
       [992, 499]])`. Is this what you data should look like?

Answer (score 0):

The question is, what to expect as an outcome when placing 1000 pixel values onto 370 screen pixels. There would be roughly 3 values per pixel, two blue, one yellow. Which color should the final pixel have?

What you can do is use an interpolation on your image together with a colormap which shows the same color for any value above 0.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

X, Y, m, s = 500, 1000, 8, 200        
x = np.zeros((Y, X)) 
c = -m * Y 

for i in xrange(Y):
    for j in xrange(X):               
        k = 0                         
        while k * s < 2 * m * Y:
            if i == m * j + c + s * k:
                x[i][j] = 1
            k += 1

clist = ((0, "w"), (1./255, "crimson"), (1, "crimson"))
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("n",clist)
plt.imshow(x, aspect='auto', cmap=cmap,interpolation="bilinear"); 
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]